# Which definition of "can" is relevant to this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> You have to pass a test before you **can** get a driving licence.
>   (Essential Grammar in Use)

[OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/can) gives the following meaning for *can*:

- (1) used to say that it is possible for somebody/something to do something, or for something to happen
- (4) used to show that somebody is allowed to do something
- (10) used to make suggestions

Which one is the meaning of *can* in the example given by *Essential Grammar in Use*?

Comment: I'd vote for #4, but, in this context, there's some overlap with #1. (That can happen sometimes, when trying to map a usage to a set of dictionary definitions; although the first _can_ in this sentence is a clear-cut #1, as you can see, but the _can_ in _as you can see_ is a blur of Nos 1, 2, and 3.)

Comment: I'd also go with #4. You must pass a test **before you are allowed to** get a driving licence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was a boy in the 1950s the schoolmarms insisted that *may* must be used for permission (your sense 4) and *can* must be used only for possibility and ability (your sense 1). But the language had already moved past the schoolmarms, and people everywhere in the English-speaking world used *can* in both senses.

Today the distinction is maintained only in contexts where permission and possibility are contrasted:

> No doubt you **can** drive at 60 mph in a residential neighborhood, but you **may** not.

In contexts such as that you provide, there is no contrast between permission and possibility: because the license is issued by a public authority there is no possibility of getting a license unless that authority permits it. Consequently *both* senses are present in *can*.